# How to invoke a non-child process from a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

A phantomjs automation app that I'm using is invoking some shell scripts, using the `spawn` command. This creates child processes. The problem is that if the parent phantomjs process dies for any reason while the child processes are running, the children get killed before running all the way through.

How can I get such scripts to continue running independently of the parent process? I assume it should be possible to have the initial spawn command invoking an intermediary shell script (that will run as a child process for a few milliseconds...) and that script will launch in some way, as "non-child" processes, the real scripts that need to be run. So the question is, how to invoke a script as a non-child process.

Comment: [nohup(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)?

Comment: Yeah, if `nohup`/etc. isn't an answer then yes a grandchild spawning method such as an intermediary shell script should work. Personally I'd probably work on making phantomjs not die in the first place though.